# Extracting a substring of a string, given the prior substring (flag?)

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string `s = "xxx -I hello yyy` and I want to extract `hello` given `-I`.

E.g. I'd like to make a function, say `findToken` that is:

```
function findToken(msg, flag, regexp) {
    return msg.match(new RegExp(flag + '\\s' + regexp, 'g'));
}
```

And then when I call `findToken("xxx -I hello yyy", "-I", "\\w+");` I get now:

`["-I hello"]`, however, I would like to get just `['hello']`, ie. ignoring the flag. How would I accomplish this using RegExp?

Comment: Use a capturing group, and access its value.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/qapoob25/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip to using exec, add a capturing group, and return the first capture in a new array:

```js
function findToken(msg, flag, regexp) {
  return [new RegExp(flag + '\\s(' + regexp + ')', 'g').exec(msg)[1]];
}

var result = findToken("xxx -I hello yyy", "-I", "\\w+");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't know much about regex but don't you think that will return only the first word?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function findToken(msg, flag, regexp) {
var match=msg.match(new RegExp(flag + '\\s' + regexp, 'g'));
    return match[0].replace(flag+' ','');
}
console.log(findToken("xxx -I hello yyy", "-I", "\\w+"));
```